# colour methods not accessible after pip install of colour-science

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

Executed the following commands:

```
!pip install -q colour-science
!pip install -q matplotlib

# Uncomment the following lines for the latest develop branch content.
!pip uninstall -y colour-science
!if ! [ -d "colour" ]; then git clone https://github.com/colour-science/colour; fi
!if [ -d "colour" ]; then cd colour && git fetch && git checkout develop && git pull && cd ..; fi

import sys
sys.path.append('colour')
```

import colour works.  However, when I call methods, it can no longer be found.  Examples of such error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colour.plotting'; 'colour' is not a package
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colour.utilities'; 'colour' is not a package
```

Answer (score 1):

This method to install `Colour` is that we use for our Google Colab environments and should not be used on personal machines. My guess is that you did a `pip install colour` instead of `pip install colour-science`.

You should instead create a Virtual Environment and install everything there. We use [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) but assuming you have `virtualenv` only:

```sh
virtualenv oklabtests
source oklabtests/bin/activate
pip3 install git+https://github.com/colour-science/colour@develop
```

Also worth noting that the main repo is available at https://github.com/colour-science/colour.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this & ten check

```
  pip3 install git+https://github.com/crowsonkb/colour@JMh
```

If you still get error please let me know

Comment: I already have. Requirements already satisfied. Still gets the error.

Comment: I've updated command, Try that, If it still exists please let me know

Comment: I also tried that earlier. That command installs 0.3.9 and shows a different error. Hehehe. Thank you though!