# Convert an RGB image to Oklab Color Space

Tags: python-3.x, colors, computer-vision

I have an image loaded using  `cv2.imread`  command in  `RGB`  format.  Is there a fast conversion/implementation of converting it to  `oklab` color space?

Tried colour-science package, however, there are problems with import and I can't explore.  The colorio on the other hand doesn't show an explicit explanation.

Please see `oklab` description [here](https://bottosson.github.io/posts/oklab/).

Comment: I think you are hoping for the impossible. For a very new project (few months), without yet interest on industry (so not much research on improvements) [and let's say...also a spamy colour space, e.g. in Wikipedia, and your link is suspect], I think it hoping too much to have optimized conversions. In the blog you have all the formula. OTOH you may want to use LCh (which is used in oklab, and it has a more solid base [and it is better then comparing Munsell (and the area of sRGB in gamut is pretty small in oklab... so you requires much more bytes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will consider your suggestion.

Comment: Can you verify that you installed `Colour` correctly, see that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66696127/931625

Comment: Hi @KelSolaar, I already made it work after Colour has been successfully installed.  Thank you!